# Typescript: Types of property 'data' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, dependencies

everyone. I'm over 4 days trying to solve the problem, but with no results so, decided to ask for help.

I have copy of the one year project (it's not mine, required to finish it), which build without any errors, but when I'm getting sources from svn and run

> npm i

Over the project I got errors: Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
I know for sure the reason is somewhere inside node_modules, but can't fix it.

I've already tried to generate package.json from working copy by `npm shrinkwrap`, use npm-collect, manually installing of all required packages. Also try to add typeRoots to the tsconfig.json - nothing.

First component

```
const renderContent = (
  widget: IDashboardWidget,
  data: IDashboardWidgetData | INodeInfoData,
) => {
  ...
  const {type: type, displayOptions, thresholds = [], id} = widget;
  {
    console.log(data);
    return <Chart id={id} displayOptions={displayOptions} type={type} data={data} thresholds={thresholds}/>;
  }
  ...
};

export default renderContent;
```

Interface that used props for Chart from the second component

```
interface IComponetProps {
  id: string;
  type: WidgetType;
  thresholds?: Array<{
    value: number;
    severity: string;
  }>;
  displayOptions: IDashboardWidgetDisplayOptions,
  data: object[];
}
```

Error

```
    Type '{ id: string; displayOptions: IDashboardWidgetDisplayOptions; type: WidgetType.line | WidgetType....' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<Pick<IChartProps, "data" | "locatio...'.
  Type '{ id: string; displayOptions: IDashboardWidgetDisplayOptions; type: WidgetType.line | WidgetType....' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<Pick<IChartProps, "data" | "location" | "history" | "match" | "staticContext" | "id...'.
    Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
      Type 'INodeInfoData | { name: string; lat?: string | undefined; lon?: string | undefined; status?: stri...' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
        Type 'INodeInfoData' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
          Property 'push' is missing in type 'INodeInfoData'.
```

devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
"@types/classnames": "^2.2.3",
"@types/cytoscape": "^3.1.9",
"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
"@types/globalize": "0.0.32",
"@types/highcharts": "^5.0.22",
"@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
"@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.109",
"@types/node": "^9.6.18",
"@types/ramda": "^0.25.29",
"@types/react": "^16.3.14",
"@types/react-click-outside": "^3.0.1",
"@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.3",
"@types/react-dates": "^16.0.6",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
"@types/react-grid-layout": "^0.16.4",
"@types/react-redux": "^5.0.20",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.6",
"@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.14",
"@types/react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.3",
"@types/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
"@types/react-toggle": "^4.0.1",
"@types/react-widgets": "^4.1.2",
"@types/recompose": "^0.26.1",
"@types/redux-form": "^7.2.5",
"@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
"@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
"globalize-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"node-sass": "^4.9.0",
"prettier": "^1.12.1",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
"tslint-config-prettier": "^1.13.0",
"typescript": "2.8.3",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1"
```

},

React:

```
"react": "^16.3.2"
```

I'm almost sure, problem in dependencies, but I can be wrong. Will be grateful for any advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I stopped on react 16.3.2 and typescript 2.8.3 versions, and I still don't know which exactly package required the source code changes, but this helps:

```
    return <Chart id={id} displayOptions={displayOptions}  type={widgetType} 
            data={data as IDashboardWidgetData}  thresholds={thresholds}/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like INodeInfoData is not an array and cannot be passed as object[]. More information would be appreciated.

Comment: this code works fine with the node_modules installed about half a year ago, but if I run npm again, I got this error

Comment: So as i said, the problem is with INodeInfoData not beeing an array. But with your code samples i cannot provide a better answer.